# 404 Not Found When Debugging, but URL Works in Browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, iis-10

I just moved from a Win 7 laptop to Win 10. When debugging the web app on Win 10, I get a 404 Not Found error. However, if I paste the URL into a browser, it works. Is there something funky about Win 10 or IIS 10 that needs to change to allow this to work? This worked just fine when debugging in VS on Win 7.

This is the JavaScript:

```
var config = {
    url: rootWebApiUrl + '/api/admin/getAdUserName',
    method: 'GET'
};

$http(config)
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.userName = response.data;
    }, function (response) {
        console.log('err: ', response);
});
```

And here is the error:

[image]

And the URL being used:

[image]

If I paste that URL into IE, it works and I get the data. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try put 127.0.0.1 instead rootWebApiUrl in url? Maybe the way of IDE deal with that could be affecting.

Comment: Using 127.0.0.1 indeed caused it to work, but why?

Comment: I answered to possibility someone make a comment assertive about the reason in IIS10 with Win10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `127.0.0.1` instead rootWebApiUrl. I believe the server doesn't know the address when is debugging, by request lookback address. Windows 10 and the new servers are more prepared to use IPv6, and only localhost affect this. Now, why this difference between normal mode to debug mode, it's not really assertive for me.